# Javac Ant task can't find a class even though it is contained in the classpath

Tags: java, ant

My `javac` Ant task produces errors like those shown below:

```
[javac] C:\dp\dev\trunk\MyProduct\MyUnitTest.java:109: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]     private MyClass createFactoryMock() throws Exception {
[javac]             ^
[javac]   symbol:   class MyClass
[javac]   location: class MyUnitTest
```

I ran the task in a verbose mode (`ant -verbose test-compile`) and found `MyClass` in the classpath output of the task, from which I conclude that `MyClass` is present in the classpath.

```
[javac] Compiling 9 source files to C:\dp\dev\trunk\MyProduct\temp\test-build

[javac] Using modern compiler
[javac] Compilation arguments:
[javac] '-d'
[javac] 'C:\dp\dev\trunk\MyProduct\temp\test-build'
[javac] '-classpath'
[javac] '[...]C:\dp\dev\trunk\MyProduct\temp\build\MyProduct\MyClass.class[...]
```

What else (apart from classpath issues) can be the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing

```
    <javac srcdir="${test}" destdir="temp/test-build" debug="${debug}" encoding="UTF-8">
        <classpath>
            [...]
            <fileset dir="${build}"/>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
```

to

```
    <javac srcdir="${test}" destdir="temp/test-build" debug="${debug}" encoding="UTF-8">
        <classpath>
            [...]
            <pathelement location="${build}"/>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it point to your exact jar files directory where the jars are present:

```
<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${main.jar}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    <!-- <pathelement location="${src.dir}" />-->
</path>
```

----in my case jar files present in ----

```
<property name="main.jar" value="jar"/>
```